# How to search for a hash key value in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
array = [
 {:name => "Bob" , :age => 27 , :place => "A"} ,
 {:name => "John" , :age => 50 , :place => "B"} ,
 {:name => "Alex" , :age => 80 , :place => "C"} 
]
```

I want to get the value of `:place` if `:name == "John"`.

However, if I use

```
array.find {|x| x[:name] == "John"}
```

I get

```
{:name=>"John", :age=>"27", :place=>A}
```

I can use

```
array.second[:place]
```

which will return `B`, but the array will have more than three Hash elements.

How can I get the right place returned on the condition of another key's value?

Comment: You could write `(array.find { |h| h["John"] } || {})["place"]` or `array.find { |h| h["John"] }&.[]("place")`. `&`, the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), causes the entire expression to return `nil` if the expression preceding `&` returns `nil`. `&` must be followed by a period, so  the method `Hash#[]` cannot be written using *syntactic sugar*. Alternatively, if appropriate, raise an exception if no hash in the array has a value `"John"` for the key `:name`.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the search in the wrong place. The array of hashes looks like you asked the database for all records and are trying to search them, but you should do that with a query of the database for that specific user. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)".

Comment: If you do it regularly, you probably should create a Hash with names as keys and age and place as values.

Comment: ...@Eric, or more generally, a unique identifier as the key.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yes, but it would not help much in order to find users by name, would it?

Comment: @Eric, I was thinking of big John Smith versus little John Smith, but yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns a hash in your case, just pass the key `:place` to get the value:

```
hash = array.find {|x| x[:name] == "John"}
return if hash.nil?
hash[:place]
```

Regarding the query about mixed values, I just tried it in IRB and it worked fine.

```
2.7.0 :014 > array = [
2.7.0 :015 >   {:name => "Bob" , :age => 27 , :place => "A"} ,
2.7.0 :016 >   {:name => "John" , :age => 50 , :place => "B"} ,
2.7.0 :017 >   {:name => "Alex" , :age => 80 , :place => "C"} 
2.7.0 :018 > ]
2.7.0 :019 > array.find {|x| x[:name] == "John"}
 => {:name=>"John", :age=>50, :place=>"B"}
```

Comment: It is returning a hash but the return is a mix between the first and the second array

Comment: I just tried in my irb and it worked fine, updated my answer. Is there anything else you are doing?

Comment: After telling me that you did exactly the same as what i was doing the whole time, I noticed a typo that I had! Thank you! :)

Comment: Although a preference I would not explicitly check for `nil` here. `return unless hash` would be enough.

Comment: `array.find {|x| x[:name] == "John"}&.[](:place)` is ugly but would work as a one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

If one needs a single method call, they might cheat `find` with even earlier return.

```rb
array.find { |h| break h[:place] if h[:name] == 'John' }
#⇒ "B"
```

Comment: Always lookin' for a way to cheat... I can't say I've seen that before! Interesting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland well, one might use `break` and `next` literally in _any_ block.

Comment: Yes, but what I find interesting is the combination of `break X` to avoid a calculation following the block and the block returning `nil` to `find` if the conditional is false.

Comment: @CarySwoveland my teammates say that the rule to accept my PR is: the number of cheats should be even so that they negate each other.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the value:

```
 p array.find {|x| x[:name] == "John"}[:place]
```

Create a method and pass `"John"` as a parameter so that you can get the value for other names as well.

Comment: What will it return when the name is not present in any of the hashes?

Comment: He is giving the model hash to us.